# Is there any good examples or tutorial about epoll UDP?

Tags: epoll

I have been working with linux server using epoll and almost finished it.
And I realized that clients will send packets using udp :(

Could you please provide me any good tutorials or example using epoll udp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man pages were helpful for me. There's also a good code example in there.

- http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html
- http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_create1.2.html

If you're really insisting on tutorial, I'd recommend:

- https://banu.com/2011/06/how-to-use-epoll-complete-example/
- https://github.com/felipecruz/rio/blob/master/src/network.c